# X86 assembly - Handling the IDIV instruction

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I am currently writing a simple C compiler, that takes a .c file as input and generates assembly code (X86, AT&T syntax).
Everyting is good, but when I try to execute a IDIVQ instruction, I get a floating-point exception. Here's my input:

```
int mymain(int x){
  int d;
  int e;
  d = 3;
  e = 6 / d;
  return e;
}
```

And here is my generated code:

```
mymain:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $3, -8(%rbp)
    movq    $6, %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rbx
    idivq   %rbx
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size mymain, .-mymain
```

According to http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html, **idivq %rbx** should produce 6/d (the quotient) in **%rax**. But I'm getting a floating-point exception, and I can't seem to find the problem.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but should you be doing `movq %rdi, -40(%rbp)` without having adjusted the `esp` register?  Or is that OK because of the x64 'red zone'?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: That's ok because the x86-64 System V guarantees a red-zone of 128 bytes below RSP; this is what mainstream compilers like GCC do: [Why is there no "sub rsp" instruction in this function prologue and why are function parameters stored at negative rbp offsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28693863).  And of course you shouldn't adjust *ESP*, that would truncate RSP to 32 bits and make later stack operations fault, if you did any before `leave`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first part of Mysticials answer is correct, `idiv` does a 128/64 bit division, so the value of `rdx`, which holds the upper 64 bit from the dividend must not contain a random value. But a zero extension is the wrong way to go.

As you have *signed* variables, you need to *sign* extend `rax` to `rdx:rax`. There is a specific instruction for this, `cqto` (*convert quad to oct*) in AT&T and `cqo` in Intel syntax. AFAIK newer versions of gas accept both names.

```
movq    %rdx, %rbx
cqto                  # sign extend rax to rdx:rax
idivq   %rbx
```

Comment: Indeed, I was running my tests and encountered an error when handling signed values. I haven't seen this instruction before, but it seems to solve the issue now. Thank you!

Comment: NASM version of the same question&answer: [nasm idiv a negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9072922)

Answer (score 13):

The [`idivq` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) divides a 128-bit integer (`rdx:rax`) by the given source operand.

- `rax` holds the lower 64-bits of the dividend.
- `rdx` holds the upper 64-bits of the dividend.

When the quotient doesn't fit into 64-bits, `idiv` will fault (#DE exception, which the OS handles by delivering a SIGFPE signal [as required by POSIX for arithmetic exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928942/why-does-integer-division-by-zero-result-in-a-floating-point-exception)).

Since you're compiling code that uses signed `int`, you also need to sign extend `rax` to `rdx:rax`, that means copying the `rax` sign bit to every bit of `rdx` and is accomplished with cqo alias cqto:

```
movq    %rdx, %rbx        # or load into RBX or RCX in the first place
cqo
idivq   %rbx              # signed division of RDX:RAX / RBX
```

---

If you'd been doing `unsigned` division, you'd zero RDX to zero-extend RAX into RDX:RAX:

```
movq    %rdx, %rbx
xor     %edx, %edx      # zero "rdx"
divq    %rbx            # unsigned division of RDX:RAX / RBX
```

---

Also note that in the x86-64 System V ABI, `int` is a 32-bit signed type, not 64-bit.  Widening it to 64-bit is legal in this case (because the result is the same) but makes your code slower, especially for division.

Comment: Zeroing rdx will work with positive numbers, but in case of negative rax probably rdx = -1 is needed... Isn't it?

Comment: I think marekb is right - shouldn't the `xorq` instrcution be a `cqo` instruction to sign extend `rax` into `rdx:rax`?

Comment: In this case, with signed typing: I think so yes.

Comment: Unsigned: `xor %rdx,%rdx` / `div`.  Signed: `cqo` / `idiv`.  Using idiv after zeroing rdx is only appropriate if your divisor is signed but your dividend is unsigned.  (And you want a signed result).  A C compiler should only generate that as an optimization after casting a `uint64_t` to an `__int128_t`, when it can prove there won't be a divide exception.  Also note that 64bit `div` is somewhat faster than 64bit `idiv` on recent Intel CPUs.