# Signed multiplication followed by signed division in YASM (x86_64 architecture)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, integer-arithmetic, yasm

I am using `yasm` assembler for `x86_64` processor architecture.
Suppose I *already* have three numbers defined in the `.data` section:

```
section .data
;CONSTANTS:
SYSTEM_EXIT    equ 60
SUCCESS_EXIT   equ 0

;VARIABLES:
dVar1    dd  40400
wVar2    dw -234
bVar3    db -23
dRes     dd  0    ;quotient
dRem     dd  0    ;reminder
```

And what I want to do is *to multiply **signed** double-word `dVar1` by **signed** word `dVar2` followed by division by **signed** byte `bVar3`.*

Below I present my "solution" with the referencing [this](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/%7Eed/assembly64.pdf) book for why do I do each step. The questions are at the end of text.

## dVar1 * wVar2 (signed)

I do not see any explicit rule that multiplication is only applied to numbers of *the same* size. But see some implicit ones. That's why I use conversion for `wVar2`:

```
movsx    eax, word [wVar2]    ;[wVar2] now in eax
```

Now "they" are of the same size so I just multiply them:

```
imul    dword [dVar1]    ;edx:eax = eax * [dVar1]
```

> ...For example, the result of multiplying **ax** (16-bits) times a word operand (also 16-bits) provides a double-word (32-bit) result.  However, the result is not placed in **eax** (which might be easier), it is placed in two registers, **dx** for the upper order result (16-bits) and **ax** for the lower order result (16-bits), typical written as **dx:ax** (by convention).

As I understand correctly, result now is in `edx:eax`.

## edx:eax / bVar3 (signed)

> ...the dividend requires  both the **D** register (for the upper order portion) and **A** (for the lower order portion)... If a previous multiplication was performed, the **D** and **A** registers may already be set correctly (which is my case [OP's note]).

and

> ...Further, the **A**, and possibly the **D** register, must used in combination for the dividend.
>
> - Byte Divide: **ax** for 16-bits
> - Word Divide: **dx:ax** for 32-bits
> - Double-word divide: **edx:eax** for 64-bits (which is my case [OP's note])
> - Quadword Divide: **rdx:rax** for 128-bits

So initially I convert `bVar3` to double-word and then just divide it:

```
movsx    ebx, byte [bVar3]    ;ebx = [bVar3]
idiv     ebx,    ;eax = edx:eax / [bVar3]
```

The whole code then

```
section .data
;CONSTANTS:
SYSTEM_EXIT    equ 60
SUCCESS_EXIT   equ 0

;VARIABLES:
dVar1    dd  40400
wVar2    dw -234
bVar3    db -23
dRes     dd  0    ;quotient
dRem     dd  0    ;reminder

section .text

global _start
_start:
    movsx   ebx, byte [bVar3]    ;conversion to double-word
    movsx   eax, word [wVar2]    ;conversion to double-word
    imul    dword [dVar1]        ;edx:eax = eax * [dVar1]
    idiv    ebx                  ;eax = edx:eax / [bVar3], edx = edx:eax % [bVar3]
    mov     dword [dRes], eax
    mov     dword [dRem], edx
last:
    mov     rax, SYSTEM_EXIT
    mov     rdi, SUCCESS_EXIT
    syscall
```

I use debugger and see the correct answer:

```
(gdb) x/dw &dRes
0x600159:   411026
(gdb) x/dw &dRem
0x60015d:   -2
```

But I am not sure about the following things.

1. Is it really necessary to do those steps I have done? Is it "the least possible number of lines" solution?
2. Is it correct solution at all? I mean I could have made a mistake or missed something important here.

---

P.S. Maybe this question is more likely CodeReview SE question. Let me know if you think so too.

Comment: Your code faults (with `#DE`, leading to SIGFPE on Linux) if the quotient of `(dVar1*wVar2) / bVar3` doesn't fit in a 32-bit register.  You could avoid that by using 64-bit multiply and divide, if that's a concern.

Comment: And BTW, optimizing asm for the lowest number of instructions (source lines) is generally not useful/important.  Either go for code-size (fewest machine-code bytes) or for performance (fewest uops, lowest latency, etc. see http://agner.org/optimize).  For example, [`idiv` is microcoded on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907523/branch-alignment-for-loops-involving-micro-coded-instructions-on-intel-snb-famil), and much slower than any of the other instructions you used on Intel and AMD CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it "the least possible number of lines" solution?

Your code looks good, and doesn't have any wasted instructions or obvious efficiency (except in your system-call, where `mov` to 64-bit registers is a waste of code-size).

But do the 2nd `movsx` after both other loads.  Out-of-order execution doesn't analyze dependency chains and do loads on the critical path first.  The 2nd `movsx` load isn't needed until the `imul` result is ready, so put it after the `imul` so the first 2 loads (`movsx` and the `imul` memory operand) can execute as early as possible and let the `imul` start.

---

Optimizing asm for the lowest number of instructions (source lines) is generally not useful/important.  Either go for code-size (fewest machine-code bytes) or for performance (fewest uops, lowest latency, etc. see [Agner Fog's optimization guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)). For example, `idiv` is [microcoded on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907523/branch-alignment-for-loops-involving-micro-coded-instructions-on-intel-snb-famil), and on all CPUs is much slower than any of the other instructions you used.

On architectures with fixed-width instructions, number of instructions is a proxy for code-size, but that's the case on x86 with variable-length instructions.

Anyway, there's no good way to avoid `idiv`, though, unless the divisor is a compile-time constant: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi), and 32-bit operand size (with a 64-bit dividend) is the smallest / fastest version you can use.  (Unlike most instructions, `div` is faster with narrower operands).

For code-size, you might want to use one RIP-relative `lea rdi, [rel dVar1]`, and then access your other variables like `[rdi + 4]`, which takes 2 bytes (modr/m + disp8) instead of 5 bytes (modr/m + rel32).  i.e. 1 extra byte per memory operand (compared to a register source).

It would make sense to allocate your dword result locations before the word and byte locations, so all the dwords are naturally aligned and you don't have to worry about performance penalties from them being split across a cache line.  (Or use `align 4` after the `db`, before the label and `dd`).

---

**The one danger here is that the 64/32 => 32bit division can overflow and fault (with `#DE`**, [leading to SIGFPE on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928942/why-does-integer-division-by-zero-result-in-a-floating-point-exception)) if the quotient of `(dVar1*wVar2) / bVar3` doesn't fit in a 32-bit register.  You could avoid that by using 64-bit multiply and divide, the way a compiler would, if that's a concern.  But note that 64-bit `idiv` is about 3x slower than 32-bit `idiv` on Haswell/Skylake.  (http://agner.org/optimize/)

```
; fully safe version for full range of all inputs (other than divide by 0)
movsx   rcx, byte [bVar3]
movsxd  rax, dword [dVar1]   ; new mnemonic for x86-64 dword -> qword sign extension
imul    rax, rcx             ; rax *= rcx; rdx untouched.

cqo                          ; sign extend rax into rdx:rax
movsx   rcx, word [wVar2]
idiv    rcx

mov     qword [qRes], rax    ; quotient could be up to 32+16 bits
mov     dword [dRem], edx    ; we know the remainder is small, because the divisor was a sign-extended byte
```

This is obviously larger code-size (more instructions, and more of them have REX prefixes to use 64-bit operand-size), but less obviously it's *much* slower because 64-bit `idiv` is slow, as I said earlier.

Using `movsxd` before a 64-bit `imul` with 2 explicit operands is better on most CPUs, but on a few CPUs where 64-bit `imul` is slow (AMD Bulldozer-family, or Intel Atom), you could use

```
movsx   eax, byte [bVar3]
imul    dword [dVar1]       ; result in edx:eax

shl     rdx, 32
or      rax, rdx            ; result in rax
```

On modern mainstream CPUs, though, 2-operand `imul` is faster because it only has to write one register.

---

## Other than instruction-choice:

**You put your code in the `.data` section!**  Use `section .text` before `_start:`, or put your data at the end.  (Unlike C, you can reference symbol earlier in the source than they're declared, both labels and `equ` constants.  Only assembler macros (`%define foo bar`) are applied in order).

Also, **your source data could go in `section .rodata`**, and your outputs could go in the BSS.  (Or leave them in registers unless your assignment requires memory; nothing is using them.)

Use RIP-relative addressing instead of 32-bit absolute: The **`default rel`** directive isn't the default, but RIP-relative is 1 byte shorter to encode than `[abs dVar1]`.  (32-bit absolute works in 64-bit executables, but [not in 64-bit position-independent executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)).

If it's ok for `div` to fault if the quotient doesn't fit in 32 bits (like your existing code), this version has all the fixes I suggested:

```
default rel      ; RIP-relative addressing is more efficient, but not the default

;; section .text  ; already the default section
global _start
_start:
    movsx   eax, word [wVar2]
    imul    dword [dVar1]        ;edx:eax = eax * [dVar1]

    movsx   ecx, byte [bVar3]
    idiv    ecx                  ;eax = edx:eax / [bVar3], edx = edx:eax % [bVar3]

 ; leaving the result in registers is as good as memory, IMO
 ; but presumably your assignment said to store to memory.
    mov     dword [dRes], eax
    mov     dword [dRem], edx

.last:                           ; local label, or don't use a label at all
    mov     eax, SYS_exit
    xor     edi, edi             ; rdi = SUCCESS_EXIT.  don't use mov reg,0
    syscall                      ; sys_exit(0), 64-bit ABI.


section .bss
dRes:     resd 1
dRem:     resd 1

section .rodata
dVar1:    dd  40400
wVar2:    dw -234
bVar3:    db -23

; doesn't matter what part of the file you put these in.
; use the same names as asm/unistd.h, SYS_xxx
SYS_exit       equ 60
SUCCESS_EXIT   equ 0
```

Style: Use `:` after labels, even when it's optional.  `dVar1:    dd  40400` instead of `dVar1    dd  40400`.  This is a good habit in case you accidentally use a label name that matches an instruction mnemonic.  Like `enter dd 40400` might give a confusing error message, but `enter: dd 40400` would just work.

Don't use `mov` to set a register to zero, [use `xor same,same` because it's smaller *and faster*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  And don't `mov` to a 64-bit register when you know your constant is small, let implicit zero-extension do its job.  (YASM doesn't optimize `mov rax,60` to `mov eax,60` for you, although NASM does).  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).

---

> I do not see any explicit rule that multiplication is only applied to numbers of the same size. But see some implicit ones.

(Almost) all x86 instructions require the same size for all their operands.  The exceptions include `movzx` / `movsx`, `shr reg, cl` (and other variable count shifts/rotates), and stuff like `movd xmm0, eax` that copy data between different sets of registers.  Also imm8 control operands like `pshufd xmm0, xmm1, 0xFF`.

Instructions that normally work with inputs/outputs of the same size don't have versions that widen one of the inputs on the fly.

**You can see that `imul` does explicitly document what sizes it works with in [Intel's instruction-set reference manual entry for it](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/IMUL)**.  The only form that does 32x32 => 64 bit result is `IMUL r/m32`, i.e. the explicit operand has to be a 32-bit register or memory, to go with the implicit `eax` source operand.

So yes, `movsx` loads from memory are by far the best way to implement this.  (But not the only; [`cbw` / `cwde` also work to sign extend within EAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217), and there's always `shl eax, 16` / `sar eax,16` to sign extend from 16 to 32.  These are much worse than a `movsx`-load.)