# Floating point exception (core dumped) need help identifying where potential error is

Tags: c, for-loop, point, floating

This function should print the averages of the odd and even inputs given from the while loop until 0 is entered, then it ends. It currently is not runnable, I split this block off from a larger section of code that had no correlation to the error. Any ideas where it would be giving the point exception error?

```
 int main()
{
    int numReturn;
    int evenTotal;
    int evenCount;
    int oddTotal;
    int oddCount;
    
    while(numReturn != 0){
      printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
      scanf("%d",&numReturn);
      
      if(numReturn<0){
          printf("That's a negative number!\n");
      }else if(numReturn%2 == 0){
          evenTotal += numReturn;
          evenCount += 1;
      }else{
          oddTotal += numReturn;
          oddCount += 1;
      }
    }

    double evenAvg = evenTotal/evenCount;
    double oddAvg = oddTotal/oddCount;
    
    printf("%d even numbers were entered and the average is %lf\n",evenCount,evenAvg);
    printf("%d odd numbers were entered and the average is %lf\n",oddCount,oddAvg);

   //some code for problem 1
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's not enough here to see where the problem is.  Please update your question to include a [mcve], including code that be compiled and run *as is*, along with input, expected output, and actual output so that other can reproduce your issue.

Comment: `oddCount =+ 1;` looks like typo

Comment: `double evenAvg = evenTotal/evenCount;` should be `double evenAvg = evenCount > 0 ? ((double)evenTotal/evenCount) : 0;`

Comment: @IłyaBursov: Zero is not the correct average of an empty set. There is no defined average, and the program should report that, not zero.

Comment: Don't know if numReturn (et al) are ints or what?  And how are they initialized.  Please update the code.

Answer (score 2):

Variables with automatic storage duration (defined inside a function without `static` or other storage specifier) are not initialized by default. When such a variable is used, it does not have a determined value (and the program has undefined behavior if the variable could have been declared with `register`, meaning its address is not taken).

When the value of `evenCount` or `oddCount` is taken as zero, a division by zero occurs in `evenTotal/evenCount` or `oddTotal/oddCount`. Likely, these are all integer variables, and this division by zero causes an exception. For [historic reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928942/why-does-integer-division-by-zero-result-in-a-floating-point-exception/16929175#16929175), this is reported as a “floating point exception.”

To resolve this, you should first initialize the local variables:

```
int numReturn = 0;
int evenTotal = 0;
int evenCount = 0;
int oddTotal  = 0;
int oddCount  = 0;
```

Additionally:

- You should make provisions in the program for when `evenCount` or `oddCount` is zero because the user did not enter any even numbers or did not enter any odd numbers. In these cases, no average is defined.
- When calculating the average, you should convert to floating-point before performing the division. `double evenAvg = evenTotal/evenCount;` will compute `evenTotal/evenCount` using integer arithmetic. Changing it to `double evenAvg = (double) evenTotal / evenCount;` will use `double` arithmetic.