# Simple x86-64 division not working

Tags: exception, assembly, x86-64, division, integer-division

For a simple test case for my compiler project, I'm trying to divide 88 by 11, but when I call `idivq` my program throws a Floating Point Exception.  Here is the relevant section of generated code where the exception occurs:

```
# push 88
movq $88,%r10

# push 11
movq $11,%r13

# \
movq  %r10,%rax
idivq %r13
```

I have looked up examples of how to use `div`, and I thought I was following the same format, so I don't understand why I am getting an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343155/x86-assembly-handling-the-idiv-instruction

Comment: Your idivq divides rdx:rax by r13.  Not setting rdx can easily cause the #DE trap.  How that produces a "floating point exception" is hard to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`idiv` concatenates `rdx` and `rax` before performing the division (that is, it is actually 128-bit division). If you want to do single-word division, put a zero in `rdx`. What you're getting is not an FP exception, but an integer overflow exception: there's something left over in `rdx` which is making the quotient too big to fit in the destination register.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense from the documents I read.  Thank you

Comment: `idiv` is signed division, so zeroing `rdx` is only correct if the dividend is positive. In general, `rax` needs to be sign extended into `rdx` (with say, `movq %rax,%rdx/sarq $63, %rdx`).

Comment: @gsg: actually there's [`CQO`](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/CWD%2FCDQ%2FCQO) for just this purpose.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky yes, although compilers seem to prefer `movq/sarq`

Comment: Might be worth it to submit a "missed optimization" bug report then :)